# Why even the conversion from byte to string is showing system.string[]

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my data base i save the data of File_Data as long blob

I write the code as follows but i am unable to get the original text

```
string deleteSQL = "Select File_Data from tblachmaster WHERE Id IN (" + gvIDs.Substring(0, gvIDs.LastIndexOf(",")) + ")";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(deleteSQL);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = gvIDs;
        DataTable dt = GetData1(cmd);
        if (dt != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[i]["File_Data"];
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                string[] lines = Regex.Split(text, "\r\n");
                string strLine = convertArrayToString(lines);
        }
}
```

Unable to get the conversion can any one help me

Comment: I would like to convert byte array to string

Comment: You are already doing that: string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

Comment: @Rewinder Ya but i am not getting the string there that's what i am asking i am getting the output as system.string[] at that point

Comment: What do you get when you run the query in SQL?? Are you sure you have some "File_Data" returned??

Comment: Ya as it is blob data i will get it

Comment: Are you sure the code that's storing the data is actually storing the data, and not, for instance, storing the literal text "system.string[]"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you are converting your inserted blob data is converted to `bytes` and inserted or not. Check for your column in MySQL editor by opening it using `Open Value in editor` select `Text` if you are able to view your data there then it is OK if not means convert the data to `bytes` before inserting to your table this will solve the issue.